# A particular manipulation of vectors

Tags: homework-and-exercises, tensor-calculus, vectors

I have a velocity vector defined as, $$V^i=\frac{dX^i}{dt}$$
Then, is the following manipulation correct?
$$\frac{\mathbf{V}\boldsymbol{\cdot}\mathbf{V}}{V^i}=\frac{V_k\delta^k_{\,\,\,\,a}V^a}{V^i}=V_k\delta^k_{\,\,\,\,a}\frac{dX^a/dt}{dX^i/dt}=V_k\delta^k_{\,\,\,\,a}\frac{dX^a}{dX^i}=V_k\delta^k_{\,\,\,\,a}\delta^a_{\,\,\,\,i}= V_i$$
If not where am I making a mistake? Please help.

**Edit:** Actually I have an expression like,
$$A_i\mathbf{e}^i=\frac{\mathbf{V}\boldsymbol{\cdot}\mathbf{V}}{V^i}\mathbf{e}^i\equiv\mathbf{A}=\frac{\mathbf{V}\boldsymbol{\cdot}\mathbf{V}}{\mathbf{V}}\implies A_i=\frac{V_kV^k}{V^i}$$
And the question is whether,
$$A_i=V_i$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your derivation fails in the third equality, when you assume that $\frac{dX^a/dt}{dX^i/dt}=\frac{dX^a}{dX^i}$. For that to be possible, you would need $X^a(t)$ to be an invertible function, which is not possible for a curve in general. That is, you cannot write $t=t(X^a)$.

Consider for example a 2D circular motion where $\vec{X}=(\cos t,\sin t)$. Given an instant of time, you can find the position uniquely. But given the position, you cannot find $t$ uniquely.

Also, note that $\mathbf{A}=\frac{\mathbf{V}\cdot\mathbf{V}}{\mathbf{V}}$ makes no sense (at least not in the usual sense of vector algebra), because the inverse of a vector is not a vector. In other words, vector division is not defined (again, not in the usual sense of vector algebra.)

Answer (score 1):

Example in 2D, but it's the same in any other number of dimensions.
Represent $\mathbf{v}$ in some basis as $(v_x,v_y)$, then
$$
A_x = \frac{v_x^2+v_y^2}{v_x} = {\bigg{|}} \frac{dx}{dt} {\bigg{|}} + {\left(
\frac{dy}{dt}
\right)}^2 
{\left(
\frac{dx}{dt}
\right)}^{-1}  
$$
and similarly for $A_y$. So, the answer is no, $A_x \neq v_x$.